# PostgreSQL & JPA - "Mixing of ? parameters and other forms is not supported" error

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-data-jpa, jsonb

I have a jsonb data column with this sample data:

```
[
  {
    "eventId": "5",
    "events": [
      "a",
      "b"
    ]
    "customerId":"123"
  }
]
```

And I'm trying to filter this data by events with the spring application. I managed to construct a working SQL query in my PostgreSQL database:

`SELECT DISTINCT jsonb_path_query(jsonb_column, '$[*] ? (@.events[*] like_regex "a" flag "i")') FROM my_table`

However, when constructing a similar @Query in JPA, and using the `?1` parameter:

```
@Query(nativeQuery=true,
        value="SELECT DISTINCT jsonb_path_query(jsonb_column, '$[*] ? (@.events[*] like_regex \"?1\" flag \"i\")') \n +"
        "FROM my_table\n"
)
```

I'm getting this error:
`Mixing of ? parameters and other forms like ?1 is not supported`

Is there a way to rewrite the original query without the use of the `?` operator? It's nested arrays, so `jsonb_path_query` comes in really handy, and I have no clue how to replace it.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Tried making a new operator in Postgre, but it doesn't work with this query for some reason.

Comment: Did you try to escape the `?` with a backslash?

Comment: @Stefanov.sm I did. Doesn't work either

Comment: Have you tried  `??` instead of  single `?`